# pymongo nested embedded document field update

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a document as:

```
{
    "name": "restaurant 1",
    "rooms":
        [
            {"name": "room1",
                "desks": [
                    {
                        "name": "desk1",
                        "unique": "abcde",
                        "busy": False
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "desk2",
                        "unique": "abcdf",
                        "busy": True
                    }
                ]},
            {"name": "room2",
                "desks": [
                    {
                        "name": "desk1",
                        "unique": "bbcde",
                        "busy": False
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "desk2",
                        "unique": "bbcdf",
                        "busy": False
                    }
                ]}
        ]
}
```

My pymongo search query:

```
db.restaurants.update(
  {'rooms.desks.unique': 'bbcdf')},
  {'$set': {'rooms.$.desks.$$.busy': True}}
)
```

I couldn't update "busy" field of the desk. $$ part didn't work. What should I replace "$$" with?

or

How can I find the index of the desk.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) it's not possible:

> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value.

Most likely you will need to redesign your database schema.

Comment: So, the only chance changing it is a for loop? without redesigning db

Comment: Yes, the only chance is to loop and run query with concrete indexes. Note, that this updates are not atomic. Depending on your application lists might be changed in the meantime by another process, so you will update wrong array item...